# Error al construir un objeto Employee a partir de un archivo .txt Exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java

Buen día Comunidad:

Tengo el sgt archivo txt.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el siguiente código intento leer el archivo y construir tantos objetos Employee como líneas tenga el archivo mencionado.

Método main:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los métodos que hacen toda la operación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La exception que obtengo es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad no sé donde incluir el método hasNextLine() Pensé que con el ciclo for basta para hacer el recorrido del archivo.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda.
DAVID.

Comment: Sería mucho mejor que en vez de hacer capturas de pantalla a tu código lo copiaras y pegaras directamente. Puedes usar Cntl+K para darle formato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes 2 `in.nextLine()` y sólo necesitas 1. El problema es que sólo tienes 3 empleados y realizas tu bucle 3 veces iniciando en el segundo empleado. Por lo que en la tercera vuelta, ya no encuentra ninguna línea.

El primer `nextLine()` está justo antes de declarar el arreglo o vector employees. Cuando haces esto, te posicionas en "Carl" por ejemplo. Pero, (ya iniciado tu clico for) en tu método readEmployee tienes otro `in.nextLine()` lo que te posiciona en "Harry", es decir, te brincaste a "Carl".

Tu bucle hace su primera vuelta con "Harry", hace la segunda con "Tony", y al hacer la 3ra vuelta, te manda la excepción.

Comment: muchas gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema está cuando lees el número de empleados:

```
String[] size = in.nextLine().split(":"); //Saltas a la segunda línea
int n = Integer.parseInt(size[1]);
in.nextLine(); //Saltas a la tercera línea
```

puesto que si te fijas en tu código en la primera línea ya estás saltando a la segunda línea con el método `nextLine`. En tu tercera línea de código (de las que he copiado arriba) vuelves a saltar otra vez a la tercera línea por lo que tu código empieza a leer los empleados desde la tercera línea y si intentas leer tus empleados, el último empleado (según tu código) lo intentará leer en la 5º línea, la cual no existe.

Usar un método `nextLine` sin guardar el valor sólo lo debes utilizar cuando uses `nextInt`, `nextDouble`, etc... que sólo leen un valor y dejan el cursor en la misma línea pero no cuando leas la línea entera.

Se me ha olvidado cómo puedes resolver tu error aunque creo que es bastante evidente. Elimina tu línea `in.nextLine();`, la cual salta a tu tercera línea y tu código funcionará sin problemas.

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: @DavidLeandroHeinzeMüller De nada :D. Recuerda que sólo puedes marcar una respuesta como aceptada, ya que he visto que primero has aceptado la mía y después la otra. No lo digo para que aceptes la mía de nuevo si no para que aceptes la que más te haya podido ayudar. Happy coding :)